# Understanding Ubuntu installation while asking password

Tags: dual-boot

While installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10 it asks me to select a password.. After doing that there are three options.. I dropped two of them -

• Login automatically

• Require password while login

Since I want to use both OS, which option will be good for me? I heard that if I choose the first option I can be able to pull the files windows to Linux vice varsa..Help me to understand what this two options work!!

Comment: Are you new to Ubuntu?

Comment: You heard wrong. Password is completely unrelated to exchanging data.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 options have nothing to do with windows.

It is the method of logging in into the desktop. The 1st does not require you provide a password to login to the desktop (but you can not use encryption with this method). The 2nd requires you to use a password for logging into the desktop.

[Examples of login sceens](https://www.google.nl/search?biw=1866&bih=980&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=ubuntu%20login%2017.10&oq=ubuntu%20login%2017.10&gs_l=psy-ab.3...28704.30542.0.30834.10.8.2.0.0.0.54.371.8.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.110...0i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1j0i8i30k1.0.bui-NR-2_8U).

Examples:

- if you are the sole use of a system and do not care about encrypting your data: use the automatic login.
- if you are not the sole user do use a login with password. If there are 2 users the 2nd one will end up with access to the data of the 1st user. That can be unwanted. Same if you want to secure your hard drive; encrypting it means you will need to provide a password to identify yourself so it has been made mandatory.